# Interpreting results from correlation, Fisher and regression

Tags: r, regression, correlation, fishers-exact-test

I am currently analyzing a data frame of two variables, power and time. Both are in discrete intervalls, power is given in natural numbers (including 0), time is given in days (format yyyy-mm-dd). All calculations are carried out in RStudio.

For correlation I calculated a value of 0,3: `cor(power, time, method = "spearman")`, time formatted to yyyymmdd as integer.

As there are too little entries per day I can't use the Chi-squared-test but the Fisher-exact-test (via `fisher.test(power, time, simulate.p.value=TRUE)`) instead. As a result I calculated a p-value of 0,3.

For regression I have used `lm(power ~ time, data = dataframe)` and as a result I calculated R-Squared = 0.07, adj.-R-Squared = 0.07 and p-value = 3,4e-09.

I assume an alpha of 5% for all test.

Now to the part where I can't interpret my results:

H0: There is no change of power with time.
H1: There is a change of power with time.

cor = 0,3 indicates there is a slight increase in power with time, the graph I create from my calculation of regression supports this as well as my p-value being below my level of significance lets me assume I should reject my hypothesis H0.

But in contrast the Fisher-exact-test with a p-value above my level of significance lets me assume that power is not depended of the time.

In my opinion these two statements contradict each other and I don't know how to interprete these accordingly?

Edit: Or is this a case of correlation vs. causality, as the results correlate (as power increases with time), but the change in time does't cause the change in power?

Comment: Everything you described lies in the realm of statistical association, that is, correlation. Conflicting statistical tests is not a sign of causation or lack of it. I'm with the impression that it's not appropriate in your case to use the Fisher-exact-test, but I may be wrong. I'm looking into it and looking forward for an answer :-)

Comment: @mribeirodantas thank you for your input. I tried using the Chi-Squared-test (which I know about the threshold of 5 entries, as below this the test tends to become inaccurate, this is why I opted for the Fisher-exact-test). Regardless, here are the results of the Chi-Squared-test, maybe they are helpful: Chi-Squared = 824,73; df = 798; p = 0.2488

Comment: I don't think the Chi-squared is appropriate here either hehe. I'm having some basic confusion about the correctness in assuming these two variables can be seen as nominal/qualitative. Maybe I'm just being stupid, I don't know.

Comment: Could you please elaborate why neither the chi-squared-test nor Fisher-exact-test are appropriate in this circumstance? For my understanding both can be used to check for dependency of one variable (the depended one, in this case power) to another variable (the independent one, in this case time). And as far as I know both can be used for metric scales (in this case power as ratio scale and time as interval scale; I hope I translated those terms correctly)?

Comment: I agree with your last comment, Fisher-exact-test and Chi-Squared test are appropriate measures for many problems. But your data does not seem the sort of data that I usually see people applying theses tests. I simulated a continuous variable here, deterministically caused by another, clearly caught by correlation (r/rho=1), and I got a p-value of 1 with Fisher-exact-test (because it's not adequate to use it with continuous data). That's why I suspect it's not appropriate for the data you that have, but I'm not a statistician, so sometimes I get confused with basic things 

Comment: ok, thank you very much for your input. Maybe someone else can tell us why I might be wrong and shouldn't use neither the Fisher-exact-test nor Chi-Squared-test as you said.

Comment: With out see the data, but I am not sure the calculations are correct.  It doesn't seem you are performing the correct analysis for both the Fisher's test and the regression using power vs time for both calculations.  The Fishers test is an analysis of the actual counts vs the expected.

Comment: Because the Fisher Exact Test simply cannot be applied directly to the kind of data you describe, we need to see the details of your calculations before we can hope to understand the question.  Alternatively, consider describing the data and your analytical objectives in more detail so we might recommend what to do.